# How do I design a site in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a site:
http://phppointofsale.com/

It has 2 "templates" or types of pages.

- The Home Page/Contact Page/Downloads pages
- Buy/Tour/Customize/Hardware/About

How would you go about developing a site for this in Drupal 7? It seems Drupal has content types, but they don't map to my idea of page types very well. Some pages have 2 or 3 blocks of content.

I am just looking for a general strategy to migrate to drupal?

(The reason I am migrating is just to learn Drupal better...I am not actually going to use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice website. IMO the most powerful module in Drupal for layout pages is Panels. CCK + Views + Panels = foundation of Drupal driven website (:

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use Paragaphs. We are working in a migration project for this website (https://lamangaclub.com) to Drupal 8 and they are so useful and give to your designs more flexibility.